# How to Download Output Widget screenshot as image In Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-plugin, flutterwebviewplugin

I want to download widgets screenshots as an image file in flutter **Web**. Is there any to do this?
By the way for converting the widget to Uint8List, I am using the screenshot plugin.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `RenderRepaintBoundary.toImage()` function to convert the widget into an image. Then you convert to `byteData`, then to `Uint8list`, then do a `base64encode` on that `Uint8List` and basically make the widget an anchor element which you can then download.

I've attached some sample code from a project that I was working on that lets the user generate a QR code and download it to the downloads folder on their PC to show what I'm talking about.

Make sure you've imported html at top of dart file:

```
import 'dart:html' as html;
```

Then, the code would look something like:

```
final key = GlobalKey();
 final qrTextController = TextEditingController();    
 //this code "wraps" the qr widget into an image format
RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = key.currentContext!
    .findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary;
//captures qr image 
var image = await boundary.toImage();

String qrName = qrTextController.text;

//running on web
  if(kIsWeb){
  print('registering as a web device');
  ByteData? byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);
  Uint8List pngBytes = byteData!.buffer.asUint8List();
      final _base64 = base64Encode(pngBytes);
      final anchor =
          html.AnchorElement(href: 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,$_base64')
            ..download = "image.png"
            ..target = 'blank';
    
      html.document.body!.append(anchor);
      anchor.click();
      anchor.remove();
    
}
```